# General Direction of Motion detection in Ultrasound [Python]

Tags: python, detection, motion

I have ultrasound videos. in the video you can detect 2 type of motions:
The transducer motion and the baby motion.
The transducer motion can be detected in the red rectangle ROI while the baby motion can be detected at the blue rectangle ROI ([Ultrasound image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CK2bz.jpg)).
I need to write a code that will detect motion of the transducer as well as the motion of the baby (Which is the relatively easy part) but I also need to detect the direction the transducer and or baby are moving in an ultrasound video.

Any suggestions on how to do that?
Rony.

Comment: primitive method to detect if there is motion (but not direction) is to compare two frames pixel-by-pixel and count how many pixels are different - and later you can assum motions when i.e. 50% of pixels are different.  To detect direction it may need to detect the same object on two frames, get positions and calculate distance - but problem is to detect object. It may need ot train Neural Network for this.

Comment: maybe author of blog [pyimagesearch](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/blog/) could help